# How can we use preinstall virtual environment from a project in Gitpod & Is it okay to put a virtual environment in a project?

Tags: python, github, virtualenv, pyaudio, gitpod

I just come across a online code editing and online project display application called Gitpod, and I was playing around with it since I thought it would be really cool to have easy access to all my Github project online especially all my Python project.
Here are my questions that I really need your guys help, since I been looking at it online and could not found the solution or that my research skills is not good yet, so really sorry If I cause any problem in advance or ask silly questions.

1. Is it okay to put a virtual environment inside each project folder, so that when you clone the project, you can just select the interpreter inside the virtual environment, and do not need to download all dependencies, since in my opinion is very efficient, since you can run the project straight away?
2. When I try to open the virtual environment in Gitpod with the pre-install virtual environment, it could not detect that virtual environment, the reason I am doing this is because when I tried to install PyAudio in the Gitpod using pip, it would not allow me, so I thought I can use the preinstall virtual environment, so I do not need to install all dependencies.

I am really sorry if I cause any problem in advance, since I am really new to community and thank you in advance and really appreciate all the helps.
Here is a picture of the structure of the file, and the Gitpod error.
[image: Here is the structure of the environment folder inside the project folder]
Here is the setting when I tried to select the virtual environment in Gitpod and select the python interpreter that come with the file.

[image: Here is the selection of the environment in gitpod]
After selecting the preinstall virtual environment, the Gitpod prompt me to select interpreter again.

[image: No environment found]

Is there an alternative work around since the main objective of this is to install PyAudio, but it said that it does not support in Gitpod, so I thought the solution to all the future problems is to install a virtual environment to all the file and run it from there would be the best option for me.

Comment: Virtualenv is not portable. Especially between Windows and Linux. Gitpod is running docker containers which are essentially Linux, so they can't possibly run python.exe pip.exe nor any Windows executables. Ok, there's wine project but that's an overkill. Your assumption that including virtualenv in the project is efficient is also false. All dependencies have to be downloaded from your repo instead of pypi. So you trade git pull time for build time without the gain you are assuming.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer to clarify and the misunderstanding that I made.